# why I am not able to see classes.dex after extraction of .apk?

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool, dex2jar

I have opened `.apk` archive file which shows me the following file:

1. Androidmanifest.xml
2. resource.ars
3. META-INF folder
4. RES folder

I am not able to get `classes.dex`. It shows me in zip folder but when I extract it classes.dex disappear after extraction.

Comment: Ans: this happens if downloaded apk sample is malicious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how that happened to you, but you can decompile the apk directly into Java source code using a tool called **JADX**. Just search it for your platform in Google.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my question and posting answer so may be helpful to someone.

Android `.apk` file  which I was using was malware sample. My Antivirus was  not allowing extraction of `classes.dex`, so it was removed by Antivirus automatically after few seconds.